# Entity saves ok but will not update record no matter what I do

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Context is not saving to the database no matter what i do it will insert a new record fine but not save. This is using sql server and the user had permissions ot update data have already checked this

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      SourceContext SourceDal = new SourceContext();

    Appointment _appointment = new Appointment();
    int errorCount = 0;

    Patient _patient = new Patient();
    _patient = SourceDal.getPatientByPatientId(txtPatientId.Text);
    _patient.SSN = txtSSN.Text;

    _patient.FirstName = txtPatientFirstName.Text;
    _patient.LastName = txtPatientLastName.Text;
    _patient.Middle = txtPatientMiddle.Text;
    _patient.AddressOne = txtPatientAddressOne.Text;
    _patient.City = txtPatientCity.Text;
    _patient.State = txtPatientState.Text;
    _patient.ZipCode = txtPatientZip.Text;


    _patient.HomePhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    _patient.WorkPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;
    _patient.CellPhone = txtPatientCellPhone.Text;

    if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
        _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
        _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    if (rBtnWorkPhone.Checked == true)
        _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;


    _patient.BirthDate = dtBirthDate.DateTime;
    _patient.emailAddress = txtPatientEmail.Text;
    _patient.Race = (int)dpRace.SelectedValue;
    _patient.Ethnicity = (int)dpEthnicity.SelectedValue;
    _patient.Language = (int)dpLanguages.SelectedValue;

    _patient.AlertNote = txtPatientNotes.Text;


    if (dpGender.Text == "")
    {
        dpGender.Focus();
        errorCount = 1;
        lblGenderRequired.Text = "* Gender is required.";

    }
    else
    {
        errorCount = 0;
        lblGenderRequired.Visible = false;
    }
    _patient.Gender = dpGender.Text.Substring(0, 1);




    _patient.PatientID = txtPatientId.Text;
    txtPatientFirstName.Text = _patient.FirstName;
    txtPatientLastName.Text = _patient.LastName;
    // IF ITS SAVE NEW GO AHEAD ADD IT TO THE CONTEXT.                
        SourceDal.AddToPatient(_patient);
}
```

Add to paitent has the following

```
public void AddToPatient(Patient newPatient)
    {
        using (var myContext = new SMBASchedulerEntities(this.Connectionstring))
        {
            myContext.Patients.Add(newPatient);

            if (newPatient.ID == 0)
            {
                myContext.Entry(newPatient).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                myContext.Entry(newPatient).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            try
            {
                myContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

It adds in the record fine but it just wont save the current record no matter what i do even though all the details are correct. But when i reload the form and the application the update is not there the email address is not saved no are any the other updates.

Comment: Are you using true Sql Server or LocalDb? Is it definitely saving to the LocalDb you think it is?

Comment: If you're sure the first block of code has no issues, please edit it off. The second block is more than enough IMO if it really is an EF issue (but LGTM).

Comment: @gldraphael the amount of code is more than fine for this quesiton as need to be showing in the context of the patient creation  alsoit is sql server thakns

Comment: When you retrieve the patient, you use the SourceContext, but when you update, you use the SMBASchedulerEntities class.  Is that working as designed?

Comment: it only adds but not updates as stated source context is a class with my method for interactiing with entity such as addtopatient so yes it is

Comment: Is this a real world app that is going to manage patient data?

Comment: @pmcilreavy what type of quesiton is that it is off topic and not  relevant to the SOq

Comment: @David there is so much code posted to SO that has obvious issues in it. For example people will often post code about an SQL query question, and the code will have a glaring SQL injection vulnerability in it. The SO community will generally point these out to help the questioner not fall victim to it even though it's not technically related to the question asked. You don't have a SQL injection issue here but there are a few issues I can see that you might want to address before you put this thing live is where I was heading is all.

Comment: Your terminology is throwing me off. Are you saying (C)reate works but (U)pdate does not? Is `AddToPatient` really meant to add new patients or update existing ones? If so, I would name it something more clear like `AddOrUpdatePatient`. Finally, if you are updating you shouldn't be doing `myContext.Patients.Add(newPatient);`, but instead `myContext.Patients.Attach(newPatient);`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect I'm not familiar with that entity framework, as I'm unfamiliar with the some of that syntax, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
public void AddToPatient(Patient newPatient)
    {
        SMBASchedulerEntities dbContext = new SMBASchedulerEntities();

        if (newPatient.ID.ToString() != "0")
        {//Update the record
            Patient updatePatient = dbContext.Patients.Single(p => p.ID == newPatient.ID);
            updatePatient.FirstName = newPatient.FirstName;
            updatePatient.LastName = newPatient.LastName;
            ...
            ...
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {//Insert a new record
            Patient insertPatient = new Patient();
            insertPatient.FirstName = newPatient.FirstName;
            insertPatient.LastName = newPatient.LastName;
            ...
            ...
            dbContext.Patients.InsertOnSubmit(insertPatient);
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

To put this another way, check to see if you need to insert or update a new patient first, before inserting it every time.